# Convert from RGB TO HSB in java

Tags: java, rgb, bufferedimage, hsb

I am trying to find the average colour in a picture, and convert the colours to HSB.

I am using a bufferedImage and the list function, and I have found the colours red, green and blue in each pixel.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to convert to HSB in java? :)

Comment: `Color. getHSBColor()`?

Comment: According to Wikipedia HSB is the same as HSV.

Comment: [Color.RGBtoHSB(int, int, int, float\[\])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#RGBtoHSB(int%2C%20int%2C%20int%2C%20float%5B%5D))

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.awt.Color.RGBtoHSB(int r, int g, int b, float[] hsbvals)`. See javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#RGBtoHSB-int-int-int-float%3aA-).

P.S. If you use `p = bufferedImage.getRGB(x,y)`, recall that the lowest 8 bits (`myPixel&0xff`) correspond to the blue component, so you may use something like: `Color.RGBtoHSB((p>>16)&0xff, (p>>8)&0xff, p&0xff, hsbvals)`.